# Select rows in one Pandas DataFrame using a column of indexes corresponding to the first frame in another

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have a match schedule, and a list of averages for each team in the match schedule. I want to add together the averages of each team in the match schedule per match.

I have two DataFrames, one of a match schedule of teams that are organized in alliances of two using a multiindex:

```
    red alliance  blue alliance      
    team1 team2   team1 team2
1   1     2       3     4
2   1     3       2     4
3   4     1       3     2
```

and one of a list of average statistics about each team, where the team number is the index (in this case, the team numbers are sequential and start from one, but the real team numbers might be like 1885, 18438, 19876, etc.):

```
        average score      average penalties
team                                    
1.      6.2.               1.1
2.      9.5.               0.2
3.      4.0.               1.3
4.      3.3.               0.5
```

I want to add a new column to each alliance in the match schedule DataFrame which contains the sum of both teams average:

```
    red alliance                                  blue alliance      
    team1 team2  averageScore  averagePenalties.  team1 team2  averageScore  averagePenalties
1   1     2      15.7          1.3                3     4.     7.3.          1.8
2   1     3      10.2.         2.4.               2     4.     12.8.         0.7
3   4     1      7.3.          1.8.               3     2.     13.5.         1.5
```

Is there any more efficient way to complete this task than simply looping through the entire DataFrame? Essentially, is there a way to generate a dataframe, series, or list from a column of indices, then add two of those (one for team1 and one for team2) together?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `.replace` to "map" all the index/values.

```
>>> df1.replace(df2["average score"]).groupby(level=0, axis=1).sum()
   blue alliance  red alliance
0            7.3          15.7
1           12.8          10.2
2           13.5           9.5
```

To get it back into the original dataframe, you could add the multi-index and use `.join`

I've not used multiIndex'd columns too much so there is probably a simpler way to write this:

```
# use as a template to build the new multi-index
columns = df1.loc[:, (slice(None), "team1")].columns

scores = df1.replace(df2["average score"]).groupby(level = 0, axis = 1).sum()
scores.columns = columns.set_levels(['averageScores'], level=1)

penalties = df1.replace(df2["average penalties"]).groupby(level = 0, axis = 1).sum()
penalties.columns = columns.set_levels(['averagePenalties'], level=1)
```

```
>>> df1.join([scores, penalties]).sort_index(axis=1)
     blue alliance                               red alliance                          
  averagePenalties averageScores team1 team2 averagePenalties averageScores team1 team2
0              1.3          15.7     3     4              1.8           7.3     1     2
1              2.4          10.2     2     4              0.7          12.8     1     3
2              1.6           9.5     3     2              1.5          13.5     4     1
```